# How to set the TTL attribute in the publish method of SNS in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, ttl

I'm writing code to send an OTP message. My current parameters and publish method look as follows:

```
params = {
  Message: otpMessage,
  MessageStructure: 'string',
  PhoneNumber: contactNo
};

sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

How do I set the TTL attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you would like to set TTL attribute when sending OTP messages but currently Amazon SNS does not support setting TTL for any of the following **:**

- ***SMS***
- ***SQS***
- ***HTTP***
- ***email***.

TTL is only applicable when sending mobile push notification using any of the following platform **:**

- ***APNS***
- ***APNS_Sandbox***
- ***FCM***
- ***ADM***
- ***Baidu***
- ***WNS***

Answer (score 0):

I set it up like this:

```
const params = {
    MessageStructure: 'json',
    Message: message,
    MessageAttributes: {
      'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.TTL': { DataType: 'Number', StringValue: '3600' },
      'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.FCM.TTL': { DataType: 'Number', StringValue: '3600' },
    },          
    TopicArn: topicArn
}
```